Can I enforce pull requests on a repo subtree?
I have a monorepo on github where I would like to enforce pull requests just in a few subtrees (corresponding to a subset of the modules contained in the monorepo).
I tried to create a ruleset on github settings where I check "Require a pull request before merging" and "Require review from Code Owners", but this setup seems to require PRs on the entirety of the repo.
Example directory structure:
root
|-moduleA/
| |...
|-moduleB/
| |...
|-moduleC/
| |...
|file1
|file...

I would like to enforce PRs for modules A and C, but let the rest be updated without going through that (direct pushes to main on those files are ok)
Is what I'm trying to do possible?
